# Pip install failed for cchardet with error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.py31compat'"

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Tried to install cchardet python module but fails with a wierd error w.r.t setuptools module

```
Collecting cchardet==2.1.7
  Using cached cchardet-2.1.7.tar.gz (653 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
     exit code: 1
      [39 lines of output]
      cythonize: ['src/cchardet/_cchardet.pyx']
      running egg_info
      creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5x5qahxb/cchardet.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5x5qahxb/cchardet.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5x5qahxb/cchardet.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5x5qahxb/cchardet.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5x5qahxb/cchardet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-wheel-qe4knwhc/cchardet_015ff5c4f63b4591bebdd029bb95c730/setup.py", line 115, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 299, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 541, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 581, in add_defaults
          rcfiles = list(walk_revctrl())
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 18, in walk_revctrl
          for item in ep.load()(dirname):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2450, in load
          return self.resolve()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2456, in resolve
          module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools_svn/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
          from setuptools_svn import svn_utils
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools_svn/svn_utils.py", line 13, in <module>
          from setuptools.py31compat import TemporaryDirectory
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.py31compat'
      [end of output]
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
      Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      See above for output.
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

When checked for the presence of 'py31compat.py' in setuptools install directory found 'py34compat.py' instead.
Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `setuptools >= 50` which [dropped Python 2.7 support](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/commit/fb7ab81a3d080422687bad71f9ae9d36eeefbee2), along with all Python releases [under 3.5](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v50.0.0/setup.cfg#L48).

`setuptools-svn` used to be directly dependent on `setuptools.py31compat` which has been removed from setuptools in v50. Fortunately, they [dropped that import it in 1.3.0](https://github.com/jaraco/setuptools_svn/commit/64b31f5b97d0dea0375846ead3deee722db4bd3b).

So you can fix your issue by doing one of the following:

- Downgrade `setuptools` to <50
- Upgrade `setuptools-svn` to 1.3.0